# What's the origin of an embedded script?

Tags: security, web, cors, xss

Suppose I embed a piece of JavaScript from B site into a page from A site. Does the B script's origin change to A?

### ADD 1

Just quote some official document:

From [RFC 6454 - The Web Origin Concept](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6454.txt).

> **3.1 TRUST**
>
> The same-origin policy specifies trust by URI. For example, HTML 
>   documents designate which script to run with a URI:
>
> `<script> src="https://example.com/library.js"></script>`
>
> When a user agent
>   processes this element, the user agent will fetch  the script at the
>   designated URI and execute the script with the  privileges of the
>   document. In this way, **the document grants all the  privileges it has
>   to the resource designated by the URI. In essence,  the document
>   declares that it trusts the integrity of information  retrieved from
>   that URI**.

And another example also from [RFC 6454 - The Web Origin Concept](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6454.txt):

> Consider, for example, cross-site scripting in HTML documents. If an
>   attacker can inject script content into an HTML document, those
>   scripts will run with the authority of the document’s origin, perhaps
>   allowing the script access to sensitive information, such as the
>   user’s medical records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scripts run using the origin of the frame they're embedded in, not the origin they were loaded from. If you load a script from another site, e.g.

```
<script src="http://example.com/example.js"></script>
```

that script will behave exactly the same as if you loaded it from your own site, or if you'd embedded it inline. It has no special permissions relative to the site it was loaded from.

Comment: Add 1 for mentioning that `It has no special permissions relative to the site it was loaded from.`.